# How to trigger jquery "on" event via ajax without user interaction

Tags: jquery

I have a call to a remote web service that returns a list of items that are then listed on the web page, 1 minute later a new list is sent and I need to take the old list, work out which items are new and then modify the list.

Step #2 in the process is to generate a list of all the currently listed items, however because they're loaded via AJAX I can't do a simple $('#items').each(); I need to use the "on" function.

The on function uses events, I can't seem to work out / find out how to have it do "on"... the request? The current way I'm doing it seems ridiculous:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#items .item').on("click", function() {
            console.log("an item");
        });

        $('#items .item').trigger("click");
    }
});
```

I'm faking the "click" event so that the "on" has something to listen for, but this seems weird.

What is the proper way to use "on" to interact with the items without faking a click event, or is faking a click event the only way to do it?

---

Edit for clarification:

Step 1. Web page loads with HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="items">

    </div>
</div>
```

Step 2. After 10 seconds an AJAX call is made to items.php, it responds with a JSON representation of the items, I then use .each to insert them into the page like so:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#content').append('<div class="item">'+value.title+'</div>');
});
```

So it now looks like

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="items">
        <div class="item">title</div>
        <div class="item">title</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Step 3. After 60 seconds another AJAX call is made to items.php again, it responds with a JSON representation of the new items. At this point I need to get the currently listed items (every .item in #items) by their title and do some comparisons on the new titles.

```
$('#items .item').each(function(){
    // doesn't work because the items aren't available 
});
```

My googling has told me I need to use "live", which has been deprecated and "on" is now used in its place...

I need a way to loop through the previously loaded elements.

---

Final Edit:

The problem did not exist, looks like I had typo'd the name of the div and in my haste I assumed that the problem was what I had experienced before: the need for on/live. Lots of previous Stack Overflow questions discussed the need for live/on with Javascript inserted HTML, however it seems that is specifically for **user interaction**. Javascript can interact with the loaded items just fine, but jquery can't act on user interactions with those items without live/on.

My bad.

Comment: I'm confused why you can't do `$.each()`. You don't have to use `each` on a physical element if that was your concern.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a selector that will query the existing items that are already in the DOM.  To do that, we need to see what your HTML is.  You don't need or benefit from `.on()` in any way here because you're just trying to query DOM elements, not handle events.  Show us the HTML of the items and we can help you with a selector query to fetch them.

Comment: You need to ask how to get the result you want, not how to hack your hacks into shape

Comment: The items are loaded via AJAX, they're not available to each. The elements exist in the DOM (because the previous AJAX call was used to place them there) but jQuery can't access them with    each    unless I use the on function. From my testing and the documentation that seems to be the case.

Comment: `$.each(data, function(){ //do stuff });`
What's wrong with `$.each()`?

Comment: @user1903372 - You have been mislead, and you must have been smoking something strong when you read the documentation? Can I have some of that?

Comment: I've added clarification to the question.

Comment: Yes, and the previously inserted elements are present in the DOM, you don't need on() or live() to access them, all you need is love, or in this case $.each.

Comment: [Refresh your knowledge](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: After removing all over Javascript and trying again it appears to work, there must be a bug elsewhere in my code. When I searched via google I came across many SO questions like this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683291/jquery-how-do-i-interact-with-ajax-loaded-content) explaining the need for live/on, are these answers incorrect or is this unique to $.each? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

your can fire this with set timeout function:

this will `fire the function after 3 seconds of wait`.

```
function myFunction(){
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {

           console.log(data);
      }
   });
}

setTimeout(function(){
    myFunction();
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try change the below lines

```
    $('#items .item').on("click", function() {
        console.log("an item");
    });
```

to

```
   $(document).on("#items .item","click", function() {
        console.log("an item");
    });
```